# Emiting signal from C++ constructor but not getting any values in qml

Tags: qt, constructor, qml, signals-slots

below is Constructor in that signal is emitting

```cpp
server::server(QObject * parent): QAbstractTableModel(parent) {

  emit messageSend("IGNORE", 0);
}
```

below is main.qml for signal handler

```js
Connections {
    target : communication
    onMessageSend : {
        var seq = num
        console.log(seq + ":" + msg)
    }
```

I have logged the values but nothing is printed.

Answer (score 1):

By the time you can get a variable pointing to your server `communication` and connect to its signal, the constructor has already been ran so the signal is emitted before the connection.

You might want to emit the signal after some delay with a QTimer, or store the information to be retrieved later.

Comment: I have defined timer in constructor like below   connect(&timerRandom, &QTimer::timeout, this, &server::readValue);      By using the timer the signal start emitting and it works for me,but is this only way ?or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for signal handlers with parameters is
`function on<SignalName>(<arguments>){}`
In you case should be something like

```js
Connections {
    target : communication
    function onMessageSend(message, seq){
        var seq = num
        console.log(seq + ":" + msg)
}
```

Or

```js
Connections {
    target : communication
    onMessageSend: (message, seq) => {
        var seq = num
        console.log(seq + ":" + msg)
}
```

[*Reference*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#signal-parameters)

Comment: This is true for Qt6, but not for versions lower than 5.15. If this were the issue, the OP would be seeing error messages.